# Is it possible to open IOS simulator while developing React-Native APP on Windows 10?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am developing an application by using React-Native. My operating system is Windows 10. I want the application to be competible with both iOS and Android. I am using Expo for the development. In expo,

[image]

There are above choices, since I don't have an iOS simulator, the second choice gives an error. How can I install an iOS simulator to my computer?

Comment: Do not forget that if you want to upload to AppStore you will need physical device to test on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, you can not create a simulator inside Windows but there are many browser-based iOS simulators available you can use them.

one is Appetize.io [here](https://appetize.io/) It is free for use but you have to upload your app manually. There are many other options available. [read here](https://fossbytes.com/best-ios-emulators-pc-windows-mac/).